# preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found

Tags: regex, codeigniter

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('ttime','Time', 'required|regex_match[/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d)$/]');
```

my regex is correct still it shows and error as
Severity: Warning

Message: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found

Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php

Line Number: 911

Comment: Try removing the extra whitespace before and after `/`.

Comment: i tried dat also..but of no use

Comment: If `regex_match[]` is a function, then I would think all the `[]` inside need to be escaped with whatever is used to separate them from the function delimiters.

Comment: I found the problem, it was "|" because CodeIgniter use "|" for separating the validator methods. so I **re_modified** my code to 

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('ttime','Time', 'trim|required|regex_match[/^(0?[1-9]'|'1[012])(:[0-5]\d)$/]|xss_clean');`

and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this problem as well. The issue is indeed the pipe `|` character that codeigniter uses, however adding single quotes didn't do it for me. Try:

1) Passing an array of rules instead of a piped string:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('field',
                                  'field name', 
                                   array('required','regex_match[/your-regex/]'))
```

2) Creating a custom callback to use with your rules as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859773/preg-match-no-ending-delimiter-found):

```
    function my_func ($field) {
            return (bool)preg_match('/your-regex-here/', $field);
    }

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('field','Field Name', 'required|my_func');
```

3) You can also use an anonymous function which is a combination of 1 & 2

Check out the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods) , I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The part 1 in Anous1000's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859773/preg-match-no-ending-delimiter-found#answer-35060853) is something what I was interested in. 
Therefore adding in it. If you're using **config** file for validation rules, instead of `set_rules()` method mentioned above, then you might be interested in

```
$config = array(
    array(
            'field' => 'field',
            'label' => 'field name',
            'rules' => array('required','regex_match[/your-regex/]')
    )
);
```